# Can't publish on mqtt broker with GO

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I have the following problem:
I can publish to an mqtt broker using java but not with go.

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        [...]

        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(jsonString.getBytes());
        message.setQos(qos);
        sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
}
```

code in GO

```
func main() {

    // Start the connection
    c := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := c.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            panic(token.Error())
    }

    payload:= "test"

    if token := c.Publish("topic", 2, true, payload); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
             fmt.Println(token.Error())
    }
}
```

Update: it must be the payload. In java I have this:

```
    String jsonString= "{\"stream\":\"temperatura2\",\r\n" + 
            "\"sensor\":\"ec6c613a-66b4-4584-fb37-5f7cac130f7d\",\r\n" + 
            "\"values\":[{\"time\":\"2019-03-10T11:30:00Z\",\"components\":{\"alfanum\":\"99.0\"}}]}\r\n";
```

I am not sure how to define the correct payload in go:

```
 payload := []byte(`{\"stream\":\"temperatura2\",\r\n" +
            "\"sensor\":\"ec6c613a-66b4-4584-fb37-5f7cac130f7d\",\r\n" +
            "\"values\":[{\"time\":\"2019-11-28:30:00Z\",\"components\":{\"alfanum\":\"1.0\"}}]}`)
```

Comment: Does the program complete its run or does it hang?

Comment: What happens if you use wrong topic? Invalid X.509 cert etc?

Comment: @kostix hi, it runs. I've seen now that it does not work without TLS also.

Comment: @kostix do you know how can I format MqttMessage in go, like I did in java: That oculd be the issue

Comment: Well, two things: if you want that JSON payload to have as a literal string constant in your program (to test things out), remove all the backslashes from it. The reason is that string literals in Go may be enclosed by either double quotes or backticks. In a literal, enclosed by double quotes, special so-called "escape sequences" are recognized, and substituted. Escape sequences are introduced using the backslash character (so, say, to have `"`in a "-enclosed string literal, you need to use `\"`). Since pretty often the need to use escape sequences produces symptomatic "baskslashity"…

Comment: …Go also supports string literals enclosed in backticks. In this case, the backslash character loses it special meaning as no escape sequences are processed in such literals. Hence in your attempt to create a string literal with JSON payload, the resulting string will have all those backslashes in it, literally, and hence the result will not be a valid JSON document. To fix your literal, 1) replace all `\"` with mere `"`; 2) remove all `\r` and `\n` — these are line terminators and are insignificant white space in JSON.

Comment: @kostix thank you very much! can you post yr second comment as a reply so I can vote it?